# Ordering system through Wordpress

Tags: order

I don't use Wordpress much, but I was wondering if anyone knew whether this would be possible in WP. Basically I want an online ordering system, so just like a normal cart where you can put things in your basket etc, except, instead of paying for it you just place an order and it  generates an order email to me?

Jonny?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is very much possible. If you want some inspiration on that, look at plugins like WooCommerce, 66Cart, and WP-Ecommerce (to name just a few). You'll want to implement it through custom post types and it will probably take a decent bit of coding to build from the ground up, but you can definitely do it.

Comment: WooCommerce actually offers a pay by cheque method, which would be fine for me!I can accept the orders and process them and then just invoice separately - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able do that with http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/eshop/ using the *cash* gateway.